Principal value integral of the negative side of the gamma function
Since the Gamma function has a pole on 0 and all negative integers, with the signs alternating, out of curiosity I want to investigate the area under gamma in the negative half-plane with all the poles cancelling out with one another. I thus consider this integral:
$$PV \int_{-\infty}^a \Gamma(x)dx$$
where $a > 0$ is some positive constant (not sure what to pick). I will be going with the case of $a=0.5$, but if there is an easier to work with value I would like to use that.
My partial progress was considering just $$PV \int_{-0.5}^{0.5} \Gamma(x) dx$$

which simplifies to:
$$PV \int_{-0.5}^{0.5} \Gamma(x) dx = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left[\int_{-0.5}^{-\epsilon} \Gamma(x) dx + \int_{\epsilon}^{0.5} \Gamma(x) dx \right] = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left[\int_{\epsilon}^{0.5}  \Gamma(-x) dx + \int_{\epsilon}^{0.5} \Gamma(x) dx \right] = \int_0^{0.5} \Gamma(-x) + \Gamma(x) dx$$
which is $\approx -0.667883...$.
However, I have been unable to determine this for the integral from $-\infty$, partially because the symmetry flipping trick for matching the bounds only works around 0. The infinite sum representation of the integral with $a = 0.5$ looks like this:
$$PV \int_{-\infty}^{0.5} \Gamma(x)dx = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{-k-0.5}^{-k-\epsilon}\Gamma\left(x\right)dx+\int_{-k+\epsilon}^{-k+0.5}\Gamma\left(x\right)dx\right)$$
which equals $\approx -0.7927059$.
Thus, my question is: is there a "nice" integral/sum representation of this value, just like with the case from $-0.5$ to $0.5$? Is this value related to any other constants? Is the choice $a=0.5$ reasonable or maybe there exists a better choice for the upper integral bound?
